# Libary missing in Android Build?

Tags: android, gradle

When I run my application in the emulator everything looks fine, if i run it on my phone, it's missing something.

I have copied a lot of code from a working app. What is missing?

[Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6y1W.jpg)

I have added the following libaries to my gradle

```
implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1"
implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.1"
```

this did not solve the problem

***Edit:***
I don't know what is missing if it is a lib or something else. As you can see on the srceenshot there is no text in the menubar, in the emulator there is. The Actionbar is not displayed correctly, in the emulator it is. You can't see it on the screenshot, but there is no spinner, in the emulator there is. The Card's do not display any text, in the emulator they are. If you click on card the text, which is bound the same way, is displayed.

Comment: can you be more descriptive ?

Comment: Sure, what informations do you need?

Comment: "if i run it on my phone, it's missing something." -- It would e.g. be useful to know, what you are actually missing. Otherwise it's hard to tell you what may be missing in your code. Some kind of code sample of a part you're suspecting to cause the failure would also be useful. Well, something more specific in any way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated my question, hope it helps

Comment: Figure out what the difference between phone and emulator is. Maybe different language? Are you sure your build succeeded fully? Have you tried to completely delete the app from both and reinstall/redeploy it? Made a clean build? Try all that and share the outcome please

Comment: The emulators are not starting anymore. I closed the app, I rebooted my computer - nothing changed. On my phone I uninstalled the app, cleaned the project and did a whole new install on my phone. The app remains the same. I have a Pixel 5 with Linode 19.1 with no google, but i had the same Result on my Pixel 2 original.